# bootstrap text comes out of span

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap css file. I have the following code  for a description area of my site, and basically I want my paragraph be inside the div class called well, but for some the paragraph keeps going out side the class well; here is the code

```
   <!--left col-->
       <div class="span8" style="background-color:black;">
    <img src="Hydrangeas.jpg">
        <div class="well" style="color:black;">  
        <p>Description of The Person in theren llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
        kljjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj jkhl kjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
        skdfkljsdklfjkllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
        skdlfjkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkpacking meeee<p>
    </p>
</div>
```

I basically want to keep the paragarph to stay inside the  Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since that text is one really long word, you need to add CSS to tell the browser to wrap it.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

It could also be that the HTML you posted is not valid. You have another opening `<p>` tag at the end of your first paragraph, and you are closing 'well' but never 'span8'.

Comment: my rest of the code has close span8, I just didnt copy and past it since, it is much longer, can I do those things inline styling?